# Adding autocomplete places google maps api search in ionic3

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am new to google apis and am trying to implement Google Map's plugin to Ionic3 but All I need to do is get the geocordinates of any place typed by the user in the search bar. Thus need to integrate the autocomplete places api to the code but seems thats not available in ionic3.

referred to following resources but no luck.

[Google auto Complete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

[Ionic Native Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/)

Answer (score 1):

Since it's just a webview, you can use the vanilla Google Maps JavaScript API in your Ionic app. Include the places library in your request for the Google Maps javascript file. Then you can use the Autocomplete Service inside your Ionic app. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/places-widget#Autocomplete

Comment: could you please share some steps to do the same.

Answer (score -1):

i am success to implement Google map Auto complete by this Github example. i hope this is also usefull for u.

link : https://github.com/danielehrhardt/Ionic-2-Google-Maps-Marker-Cluster

Comment: There's no documentation to integrate it could you please share some steps to integrate it.

Comment: just download and check how it works.i try same for that